# Difference between commonly used Classes (Targets) like Windows XYZ Operating System & Computer

Tags: system-monitoring, system-center, scom

I am a beginner in SCOM management. So far i was able to do a lot of things in it - all with the help from Technet and sometimes trial-error experiements. I tried to avoid posting this, read a lot of docos like MP guides but unfortunately they doesnt explain my question.

Question) I am trying to override a Monitor to a specific class. I see there are many targets which are similar in name.

I know what it means when it has Windows 10 or Windows Server or Core, full, Nano in a target's name. But what is OS, computer, computer group, etc...

**Operating System:**

- Windows 10 Operating System

**Computer:**

- Windows 10 Aggregate Computer
- Windows 10 Computer
- All Windows Computers
- Windows Computer
- Computer

**Group:**

- Windows 10 Computer Group
- Windows 10 Instances Group

Hope somebody in here can help me. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already gotten your answer, but just in case.

The Management Pack developer creates class names; sometimes, they can be confusing.

The simplest way to determine which class to use or to distinguish between classes is to use the Monitoring\Discovered Inventory node in the SCOM console.  Change the Target Type to the class you are curious about, and a list of objects should be displayed.

Hopefully, that sheds some light on what the differences are.